# Getting multiple emails with power Automate trigger

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, power-automate

I am trying to trigger an email from Power automate function in power BI. So basically, I included 1 column of the table and multiple measures in value field. My flow is very simple as below

[image]

But when I trigger the function, I get multiple emails. I am not sure how to fix it as i am very new to this. But when i remove the column from the values field, I am getting a single email with all the measures in right place. But that doesn't really serve my purpose as my table should contain the table. Is there way i can fix this?

Comment: Sorry, too hard to help. Show us the data and what you want the email to look like.

Comment: My Bad @Skin 

I want the email to look like the below:

Dear Leaders, 
 

1. We received a total of <Measure1> demands 
2. Attended <Measure2>
3. <Table from Compose1>


Overall, this is a simple table. I cant seem to keep measures and tables in a single email

Comment: Show me the json you’re dealing with from PowerBi.